# Why does this sentence, return false, when asked if it is a string?

Tags: javascript, string

Sorry if this question sounds basic, but I can't find an answer to it online.  When I asked the console, if this string is a String, it says false. Why?

```
"i am a string" === String; //outputs: false

var x = "i am a string"; 
x === String; //outputs: false

x != String; //outputs: true
```

This is the real reason I went into the console.

```
var myWonderfulArray = ["one", "two", 4,6, "five"];
function someFunction(element){
    return element === string;
}
myWonderfulArray.some(someFunction);
```

and it outputs this errror: uncaught ReferenceError: string is not defined

I don't understand at all!  Because it is actually a string, like there are strings in there.

Comment: You want `typeof`.

Comment: It is _a string_, it is not _String_ itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use **comparison operators (==, ===, !=, !==, <, >, <=, >=)** when you want to compare **values**. If you want to check if a variable is a `string`, use the `typeof` operator.

Ex:

```
typeof "i am a string" == 'string'    //outputs: true

var x = "i am a string"; 
typeof x === 'string'               //outputs: true

typeof x != 'string'               //outputs: false
```

You can learn more about comparison operators [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison), and the `typeof` operator [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

Comment: @Dai , just updated it, thanks for the heads up. :D

Answer (score 4):

- `x === String` means "is `x` exactly equal to the `String`-prototype-constructor-function", which it isn't.
- To compare types in JavaScript, [use the `typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

  - JavaScript has only a few fundamental data-types:

    - `string`
    - `number`
    - `object` (this is also the type of `null` values)
    - `undefined`
    - `boolean`
    - `bigint`
    - `symbol`
    - `function`
  - Note that the `typeof` operator always returns **a `string`** value with the name of the (fundamental, or intrinsic) type.

    - The `symbol` type was added to JavaScript only very recently, which is why `typeof` returns a `string` instead of a `symbol` value - in case you're wondering.
- Don't confuse JavaScript types with Object prototypes. You cannot use `typeof` to determine an `object`'s prototype - you need to use `instanceof` for that, but `instanceof` is not reliable because JavaScript does not use nominal typing (this is why TypeScript has type-guard functions to assert structural types).

Your code should look like this:

```
typeof "i am a string" === 'string'; //outputs: true

var x = "i am a string"; 
typeof x === 'string'; //outputs: true
```